# Rolling dice Probability that Sum

Tags: probability, dice

If 10 pairs of fair dice are rolled, approximate the probability that the sum of the
values obtained (which ranges from 20 to 120) is between 30 and 40 inclusive.

I dont know where to start with this one. I have been looking all over the web for example, but nothing i find is applicable for finding the sum of numbers.

any advice would be great

Comment: Start by listing the combinations of numbers that result in a sum between 30 and 40.

Comment: i dont think so man, the combination would be almost endless.

Comment: That depends on one's understanding of almost endless. I admit that I overlooked the word 'approximate' in your question, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are tossing $20$ dice. Let $X_i$ be the number showing on the $i$-th die. We are interested in the random variable $X_1+\cdots+X_{20}$.

The $X_i$ are independent, mean $\frac{7}{2}$, variance $\frac{35}{12}$ (please verify).

So $Y$ has mean $\mu=20\cdot\dfrac{7}{2}$, variance $\sigma^2=20\cdot \dfrac{35}{12}$.

We cross our fingers and use the **normal approximation**. This is because $Y$ is the sum of a not terribly small number of independent identically distributed respectable random variables $X_i$.

So we want the probability that if $W$ is *normal* with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $30\le W\le 40$.

The rest depends to some degree on whether you are expected to use the continuity correction.

**Without** the continuity correction, we want the probability that a standard normal $Z$ satisfies $\frac{30-\mu}{\sigma}\le Z\le \frac{40-\mu}{\sigma}$.

**With** continuity correction, replace $40$ by $40.5$, and $35$ by $34.5$.

If you have any difficulty finishing, please leave a comment.

Comment: i never heard of "continuity correction" so i guess not. Im working on it all now, thanks.

Comment: When we are using the normal to approximate, for example, a binomial $X$, the probability that $X\le k$ is often better approximated by the probability that $W\le k+\frac{1}{2}$, where $W$ is the normal with same mean and variance. (The no continuity correction uses $\Pr(W\le k)$.) Makes no significant difference if $n$ is large, like $400$. But for smallish $n$, the correction often leads to improved estimates. **If** your course has not discussed it, you are not expected to use it! I was just being cautious.

Comment: So here is what i got P(z <= 40 - 70 / 175/3) = .303 and P(z <= 30 - 70 / 175/3) = .246. So, .303-.246 = 0.057

Comment: Should the Variance be $sqrt(20)*35/12

Comment: The standard deviation of $Y$ is about $7.6376$. The prob. that $Y\le 40$ is roughly the probability that $Z\le \frac{40-70}{7.6376}$. This is virtually $0$. I suspect there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: The variance is $(20)\frac{35}{12}$. You get a square root when you take the standard deviation.

Comment: Yes i see, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's $x_1,\ldots x_{20}\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For a exact solution 
$$
P\left(30\leq x_1+\ldots+x_{20}\leq 40  \right)=\frac{1}{20^6}\sum_{30\leq N\leq 40}\quad\sum_{x_1+\ldots+x_{20}\leq N} \frac{N!}{x_1!\cdot \ldots \cdot x_{10}!}
$$