# Probability of Dice

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, dice

Q) If 20 fair dice are rolled, then the probability that the sum obtained is between 30 and 40 is 0.325. True or False?

A) So far I have that $ \mu = \frac{7}{2}$ and $ \sigma^2 = \frac{35}{12} $. So for 20 rolls $ \mu = 20 \times \frac{7}{2} $ and $\sigma^2 = 20 \times \frac{35}{12}$. So using the continuity correction we have $ \frac{29.5-\mu}{\sigma}\leq z \leq \frac{40.5-\mu}{\sigma}$. However, this gives the probability equal to $0.0001$ using the normal distribution tables. I don't know if what I have done is right and the statement is false or if I have made a mistake somewhere.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that $\mu = 70$ for $20$ dice. The probability that you get about half that on so many dice _should_ be low. At the very least it shouldn't be over $30\%$.

Comment: So my solution should be correct and either way I can state that the probability shouldn't be over 30% as the mean is 70.

Comment: Since the mean is $70$, the intervals $40-50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-80, 80-90$ and $90-100$ are all more likely than $30-40$, and $100-110$ is as likely. They can't all be over $30\%$.

Comment: @Arthur you should post that as an answer

Comment: Are the dice six-sided?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352260/rolling-dice-probability-that-sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.  Arthur's argument is a proof, and your calculation is fairly persuasive

The true figure is closer to $0.00003$.

You can find it with the recursion $\displaystyle P_6(s,d) = \sum_{i=1}^6 \dfrac{P_6(s-i,d-1)}{6}$ starting at $P_6(0,0)=1$

which for $d=20$ gives the following probabilities for different sums

```
 s  Prob
30  5.430E-09
31  1.471E-08
32  3.763E-08
33  9.141E-08
34  2.118E-07
35  4.699E-07
36  1.001E-06
37  2.055E-06
38  4.071E-06
39  7.801E-06
40  1.449E-05
```

adding up to about `3.025E-05`